# PHP error alert that doesn't redirect but stays on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I am trying to do some form validation before the form submits to the database. I would like the error message to display if all the fields don't have values but currently, when submitting, the form redirects to the same page and wipes everything from the form. Heres my code..

```
$error = '';
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'], $_POST['short_desc'], $_POST['file'])) {
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $content = $_POST['content'];
            $short_desc = $_POST['short_desc'];

            $targetDir = "../images/blog-images/";
        $fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
        $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');
            if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath);
            }

        //if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
        //  $error = 'All fields are required!';
        //  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$error');</script>";
        //} else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO articles (article_title, article_content, article_timestamp, article_short_desc, article_image) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');

            $query->bindValue(1, $title);
            $query->bindValue(2, $content);
            $query->bindValue(3, time());
            $query->bindValue(4, $short_desc);
            $query->bindValue(5, $fileName);

            $query->execute();
            header('Location: add-new-post.php');
        }else {

        $error = 'All fields are required!';
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$error');</script>";
    }

    }
```

Is there a way to do this without AJAX as I am not too familiar with it..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could simply require the input fields. Then there will be a message saying that the empty field has to be filled out

Comment: add your Form HTML code as well to get understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Since your PHP script is on the same page as the HTML form it seems, you can do something like:

```
<input type="text" name="someField" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['someField']) 
? $_POST['someField'] : '' ?>" required />
```

The `required` flag at the end will prevent the form to be submitted on the front end part if its unfilled. The `value` field will re-fill the input with the last variable that was passed through POST.

In your case you could use one or the other.